# java RGB color space to YCrCb Color space conversion

Tags: java, image, image-processing, color-codes

Please i need help regarding changes of color space

I have calculate Y, Cr , Cb values using conversion

```
            int Y = (int)(0.299*r+0.587*g+0.114*b);
            int Cb=(int)(128-0.169*r-0.331*g+0.500*b);
            int Cr =(int)(128+0.500*r-0.419*g-0.081*b);
```

Now i have to save new image with new color space e.g YCrCb not RGB what should i follow.

Comment: I need image in jpg format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the image in YCbCr space using bufferedImage  class in java. For this create an empty buffered image of size same as your RGB image and set all the pixel values using setRGB method as shown below.

```
BufferedImage ycb =  new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int val = (y<<16) | (cb<<8) | cr;
    ycb.setRGB(i,j,val);

ImageIO.write(ycb,"png", new File("E:\\Rose\\ycbcr\\ycbcr.png"));
```